# NTRU cryptosystem lattice reduction attack

Tags: cryptography

I need help understand the attack on NTRU cryptosystem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt

For example:

Given Alice’s public key: q = 131 and h = 100. Suppose that Bob sends the encrypted message e =78. I do the attacker find his message m before encryption?

Attempt:

The relevant lattice L is the one with the basis (1,100), (0,131).
I can use Gauss’ lattice basis reduction algorithm to find a reduced basis of L: (4, 7), (-13,  10)

So I can guess f=4, g=7, then calculate

$a=fe \mod q = 50$

$m=f^{-1} a \mod g =2$?

I cannot validate this with $1 \leq r \leq 8$:

r=5: $e=r*h+m \mod q=72\ne78$

r=6: $e=86$
...

[An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography](https://github.com/isislovecruft/library--/blob/master/cryptography%20%26%20mathematics/An%20Introduction%20to%20Mathematical%20Cryptography%20(2014)%20-%20Hoffstein%2C%20Pipher%2C%20Silverman.pdf) has a section 7.13.1 Gaussian Lattice Reduction on page 436

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the attack described in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: Just the lattice reduction attack, wiki had a few other methods that I haven't explored